# Kitura iOS server

Tags: ios, xcode, server, kitura

I'm trying to figure out how a server can work on an iOS device. And I found [this fantastic tool](https://developer.ibm.com/swift/2017/03/13/kitura-ios/).

I'm trying to follow [this example](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-HelloWorld-iOS). Following [these](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-HelloWorld-iOS#quick-instructions) instructions, everything seems to work, but when I open EndToEnd.Xcworkspace, Change scheme to "ClientSide" and build, I get the following error: `<unknown>:0: error: missing required module 'CHTTPParser'`, also report [here](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-HelloWorld-iOS/issues/11) .

I also saw that a similar error was reported [here](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-HelloWorld-iOS/issues/6) as well, and seems to have been fixed [here](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-HelloWorld-iOS/commit/de48561b55799998fc1456d65578e8dbacb2c1df), at least in xcode 8.3.1 and 8.3.2 (I use 8.3.3).
In a comment it is written: "remove ServerSide and rerun make", I have tried but the error persists.

Any suggestions ? Which may be the cause of
Missing required module 'CHTTPParser'

Answer (score 0):

@emacos Let me debug it during the weekend.

July, 23, 2017 Fixed in this PR - https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-Builder-iOS/pull/1

Comment: If this one can help you, I've been able to build in xcode 8.3.3 and 8.3.1, like this:
1- build normal and get the usual error: 
`<unknown>: 0: error: missing required module 'CHTTPParser'`
2 - copy `module.modulemap` 
from 
`... Kitura-HelloWorld-iOS / ServerSide / KituraHelloWorld.xcodeproj / GeneratedModuleMap / CHTTPParser /` 
 to
 `... Kitura-HelloWorld-iOS / ServerSide / .build / checkouts / Kitura-net.git - 7410958935072501107 / Sources / CHTTPParser / includes`
 Build and run project, and everything works .

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this is the issue, for some reason Xcode 8.3.3 stopped to handle the generated module maps correctly. I will open a defect against apple and will see how the issue can be worked around.